# Internet explorer fails to play WEBM when encoded with FFMPEG

Tags: internet-explorer, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, webm

I am creating a video hosting site where users can upload videos which are then converted into a web viewable webm format via FFMPEG, but I seem to have a problem getting the HTML5-video to work on Internet Explorer (IE 11, Windows 8.1, webm extensions installed).

The standard 'Big Bunny Buck' video (found here: http://www.webmfiles.org/demo-files/) works fine on IE, but if I convert a video to webm using FFMPEG it doesn't play at all but simply states 'Invalid Source' on the HTML5 video element.

I am using these commandline args to convert to webm on FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i bunny.webm -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -f webm bunny2.webm
```

Its werid as the videos work fine on VLC, windows media player, Firefox and Chrome but not on IE. Anyone ran into this issue before or could offer any pointers of how to fix it?

You can download this example zip (https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhp64c4rh7xqttj/IE-Webm.zip) which includes a bat script to run the above FFMPEG arguments and a html page for rendering two video elements for the before and after encoding with FFMPEG.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16961377/32453 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487085/ffmpeg-convert-html-5-video-not-working or http://docs.sublimevideo.net/encode-videos-for-the-web or http://johndyer.name/ffmpeg-settings-for-html5-codecs-h264mp4-theoraogg-vp8webm/ maybe?

Comment: It's not a server issue as the example zip shows unfortunately. It seems to be a problem with the way FFMPEG encodes the video into the webm format.

Comment: Did you copy the valid Big Buck movie to your server and played from there or did you only test on the source site? If you didn't copy the movie to test you could have a missing mime-type setting on the server.

Comment: The valid Big Buck movie works from the server.

Comment: @rogerdpack libav seems to work! I guess I have to build my own FFMPEG with the latest libav?

Comment: what libav are you using? what is the output of `ffmpeg -i movie_filename` for both the libav version and ffmpeg version [which might explain a difference].  Either way this feels like possibly a bug in ffmpeg...?

Comment: Here are two info dumps from MediaInfo: 
http://pastebin.com/YmRQvDqs
http://pastebin.com/tuWaf3QC
Only difference seems to be the format version and writing application/library version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded the latest version and seems to have sorted it, I must have just been really unlucky and grabbed a build that was broken!

Answer (score 0):

- IE 11 see

Deprecated Elements msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Elements msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

- Please use this emulation   
  e.g. BGSOUND is able with this emulation
- Do not forget: In IE 11 you cant use   attachment !!!!!
- html document begin must be

< !DOCTYPE HTML >
< HTML LANG="xx" >    < !-- xx like en or de ... -- >

- Install codecs for WebM and Ogg.
- FFMpeg library must include webM library http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/
- Other informations see  http://www.twseiten.com